Expo 51 Fails when building ease for Android on development profile
I am digging into this since a week
I am on Expo 51 "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^14.2.1 On Ubuntu
ios successfully build ease for development, But android fails with :

Configure project :react-native-google-mobile-ads
:react-native-google-mobile-ads package.json found at /home/nimer/apps/alarab3/node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/package.json
Error: /home/nimer/apps/alarab3/android/gradlew app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86_64,x86,arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a exited with non-zero code: 1

Now Expo askes to put the app ids inside expo object -> plugins - > react-native-google-mobile-ads:
{

"expo": {
"name": "alarab3",
"slug": "alarab3",
"version": "1.0.0",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",
"userInterfaceStyle": "light",
"splash": {
"image": "./assets/splash.png",
"resizeMode": "contain",
"backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
"ios": {
"supportsTablet": true,
"bundleIdentifier": "il.co.mobile1.alarab",
"infoPlist": {
"UIBackgroundModes": [
"fetch",
"remote-notification"
]
}
},
"android": {
"adaptiveIcon": {
"foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
"backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
"package": "com.gaiamobile.alarab",
"googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
},
"web": {
"favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
},
"plugins": [
[
"react-native-google-mobile-ads",
{
"androidAppId": "ca-app-pub-6286298976142792~3669494415",
"iosAppId": "ca-app-pub-6286298976142792~5668987709"
}
],
[
"expo-font"
],
[
"expo-build-properties",
{
"ios": {
"useFrameworks": "static"
}
}
],
"pushwoosh-expo-plugin"
],
"extra": {
"eas": {
"projectId": "89ec0e33-0e51-4aa5-9359-8b079f1762c7"
}
}
}
}
Any thing can help?
Thanks
